# Simple addition exposes Javascript engine floating point error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, floating-point

While working on [measurement.js](https://github.com/Philzen/measurement.js), the joys of TDD helped me stumble upon a really strange (at least as i occurs to me) behaviour exposed in the javascript engines.

No matter if entered into the console or performed inside a script, this is what happens:

```
-1 + 0.85     --> -0.85               ✓  
-1 + 1        --> 0                   ✓   
-1 + 1 + -.15 --> 0.15                ✓
-1 + 1.15     --> 0.1499999999999999  ?!?
```

This is tested and reproduced exactly under following Browsers / OS's:

- FF 24.0 (Debian 3.10)
- Chrome 30.0.1599.114 (Debian 3.10)
- Chrome 30.0.1599.101m (Win7SP1)
- Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16721 (Win7SP1)

As this is consistent throughout different vendors, i assume there must be a specific reason for this, so:

- What is the reason for this?
- What is the best practice to circumvent this behaviour, as it poses a problem for exact calculations with JS

---

**Update**:
Best lay-comprehensible explanation incl. answers and workarounds for multiple programming languages so far found at
http://floating-point-gui.de/  (thanx @RocketHazmat)

Comment: Damn you IEEEEEEEEEEEE!!!!!!!

Comment: Check out http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate as the OP is also asking the best practice to circumvent this behavior (however it should probably be worded differently then).

Answer (score 0):

No duh. You try doing the math in base two.

Short answer: you can't do it. It's like trying to add 1/3 in decimal repeatedly. You get 0.333333, then 0.666666, then 0.99999... but shouldn't that last one be 3/3, in other words 1?

To avoid this problem, just use integers for everything, as much as possible.

Comment: +1, but `just use integers for everything, as much as possible` - was that a joke?  Isn't the solution to use toFixed before presenting the results to the client?

Comment: "No duh. you try doing the math" - unhelpul, now i feel more stupid than before. "just use integers for everything" - so what you'd suggest as an integer representation of 1.15 ?

Comment: @AdamRackis: That wasn't a joke.  With money for example, do the math in "cents".  Instead of doing `0.1+0.2`, do `10+20`, then convert to dollars later.  `(10+20)/100 => 0.3`

Comment: @Philzen: Times it by 100, do the math, then divide by 100.  `(-100 + 115)/100 => 1.5`.  Or use `toFixed`: `(-1 + 1.15).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - thx, that's heaps better and actually answers half of my question. I'll try to read through the referenced links and see if i can grasp why this isn't done internally anyway (i mean any cheap desktop calculator gets this addition right, shouldn't JS do it as well?)

Comment: @Philzen: Check out this page: http://floating-point-gui.de/  It should explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of the problems inherent in representing some floating point numbers in binary.

Read this:- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Try to use **[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** to avoid  your problem

> Formats a number using fixed-point notation.